# $x^3-6x^2+11x+m=0$ roots in arithmetic progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, parametric, arithmetic-progressions

> Given equation:
>   $$x^3-6x^2+11x+m=0.$$
>   For which values of $m$ roots of the equation are  roots in arithmetic progression?

I've found a version of this exercise in which the equation could be converted to a quadratic by letting $y$ be $x^4$, but I couldn't really come out with a method that works here as well from that.

I've applied Vieta's and got $x_1^3+x_1^23r+2x_1r^2+m=0$(from $x_1*x_2*x_3=-m$, r being the ratio of the progression) and also $x_1= \frac{11-2r^2}{6+3r}$(from working with Vieta's) but I don't think replacing $x_1$ in the previous one would be the way to go.

Can I have some hints on how to approach this? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: the sum of the roots is $6$, so one root is $\;\cdots\;$

Comment: I think the problem here may be that Alexander misread "arithmetic progression" and instead thought it said "geometric progression" (hence the use of "$r$ being the ratio of the progression"). Alexander: try putting the roots in ARITHMETIC progression, i.e., $a$, $a + q$, $a + 2q$.

Comment: I've just used the letter r instead of q, but applied it as in your example. @JohnHughes

Comment: Then how did you get $3r$ as the coefficient of the quadratic term? It should be the sum of the three roots, which is NOT (in my notation) $3q$.

Comment: I did $x_1(x_1+r)(x_1+2r)=-m$ @JohnHughes

Comment: @Alexander For terms in AP it makes more sense to use $x_1+(x_1+r)+(x_1+2r)= 3(x_1+r)\,$. Since the sum is $6$ by Vieta's formulas, this gives you the middle root directly.

Comment: That product gives you the *constant* term, not the coefficient of $x^2$.  The coefficient of $x^2$, which is the *sum* of the roots, is ... well, you work it out.

Comment: That was the thing I was missing, thank you. @dxiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ be our roots.

Thus, $$x_1+x_2+x_3=6$$ or
$$3x_2=6,$$ which gives $x_2=2$ and from here we can get the value of $m$:
$$8-24+22+m=0$$ or
$$m=-6$$ and easy to see that this value is valid:
$$x^3-6x^2+11x-6=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3).$$
Done!

Comment: It was so simple !

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, but we need to check that it's valid.

Comment: That's right. For this you can for instance divide the given polynomial by $x-2$ and study the resulting quadratic. Or use Vieta. And in the end it is not simpler than my solution :-(

Comment: @Yves Daoust I think  It's easy: $x^3-6x^2+11x-6=x^3-2x^2-4x^2+8x+3x-6=(x-2)(x^2-4x+3)=(x-2)(x-1)(x-3).$

Comment: You could just have used long division, but actually, given the hint by @orangeskid, the validity is implied.

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes, it's nice, but we need to prove it. It takes a bit of time, but it's nice of course.

Comment: Mh, by symmetry around the inflection point.

Answer (score 2):

Using the roots $a-d,a,a+d$, the conditions are

$$3a=6,\\
3a^2-d^2=11,\\
a^3-ad^2=-m.$$

Then

$$a=2,d=\pm1,\\m=-6$$ and this is the only solution (though there are two progressions, $1,2,3$ and $3,2,1$).

Answer (score 1):

If we deflate the polynomial using $y=x-2$, the roots remain in an arithmetic progression

$$x^3-6x^2+11x+m\to y^3-y+m+6.$$
The deflated polynomial needs to be odd (of the form $y(y^2-d^2)$), and this works with

$$m+6=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The roots of $P$ ($\deg 3$) are in arithmetic progression if and only if their arithmetic mean $\frac{s}{3}$ is a root, that is 
$$P(\frac{s}{3})=0$$

Answer (score 0):

you will have $$x_1+x_2+x_3=6$$ and $$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=11$$ and $$x_1x_2x_3=-m$$ where
$$x_2=x_1+d,x_2=x_1+2d$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the roots be $a,a+d,a+2d$ then we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+a+d+a+2d=3(a+d)=6 \\
\color{red}{a+d=2} \\
a(a+d)+a(a+2d)+(a+d)(a+2d)=\color{blue}{3a^2+6ad+2d^2 =11}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now square $\color{red}{a+d=2}$ , multiply it by $3$ and subtract the last equation to get $d^2=1$. It is easy form here ?

Comment: It's easier to let the roots be $a-d, a, a+d$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x)=x^3-6x^2+11x+m$.
Change $x=y+2$ to get
$$Q(y)=P(x+2)=(y+2)^3-6(y+2)^2+11(y+2)+m=y^3-y+6+m$$

The roots of $P$ are in arithmetic progression if and only if the roots of $Q$ either are.

Since the sum of the roots of $Q$ are $0$, the roots of $Q$ are $-u,0,u$ for some $u\ge 0$. Since $0$ is a root of $Q$, we get $6+m=0$.